# Microsoft testing framework measure time

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2010

Is there any build in features I may measure code/methods execution time using visual studio 2010 in Microsoft testing framework ?

Or only Stopwatch may help?

Comment: [See this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7815534/how-can-i-precisely-time-a-test-run-in-visual-studio-2010)

Answer (score 0):

You can also see test method duration from the *Test Results* window. Right click on the column header, choose *Add/Remove columns...* and check the columns you want.

I don't know how exact this is, because it is not clear to which extend test runner execution itself might be included in the measures but it should give you at least reasonable indications.

HTH.
Thomas