# How can I precisely time a test run in visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, mstest

I have a suite of unit tests for my project which I run using the visual studio test runner. I want to know how long the test run takes when it runs. The test run details screen shows me the start and end times of the run, but only to the nearest second. My test suite at the moment is taking less than a second to complete, so I can't tell if my suite of 50 tests is taking < 0.1 second (good!) or up to 1 second (bad!).

Is there any way to enable this level of precision?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your root solution directory, there is a folder called Test Results following the test runs.  If you look in there, each run spits out a .TRX file with timestamp of the test run as part of its name.  Open this file, and you'll see that it's an XML file with a bunch of hard-to-read information about the test run.  If you look for the XML nodes "UnitTestResult", each will have an attribute called "duration".  This will tell you how long each individual test took to run (assuming the test was run).

I have a good bit of experience with this as I wrote an open source utility that takes these TRX files, parses them, and generates an HTML report of the results.  One of the things that it shows you is test time duration, for individual tests, test classes in aggregate, and the test run as a whole.

Lest this come off as a plug for my tool, I won't post the link unless someone is curious.  But, suffice it to say, you can get the test's execution time from the TRX file without debug trace or the console or editing your test code.

Edit:  And the precision is ridiculously high.  Example entry is 00:00:00.0015890 for a single unit test.

Comment: Just discovered that in the Visual Studio 2010 Test Results window you can add a "duration" column that displays this value. I might like your way better. :) Do you know if this value is hidden in the TestContext somewhere?

Comment: The only place I can imagine it being in the TestContext would be indexed in the instance property "Proprties", but I admittedly don't know much about using TestContext in code.  I don't typically use it as I don't use MS Test for integration tests.  (Not saying that's the only reason one might ever use it -- I've just never had a need for it).

Comment: Nice catch on the optional column in the results window, by the way.  I customized that a long time ago and haven't looked at it since, so I've never used that column.

Comment: I just set a break point and drilled into a TestContext. It contains an m_currentResult that is private. I don't see a public way to get to the duration in code. Seems parsing it from the results file is the only way (without hacking) to get the value.

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer - I'll probably just add the extra column as suggested in ErnieL's comment, but you pointed me to the .trx file which, I notice, stores the start and end time of the entire run to the same level of precision as the duration column shows for each test.

Comment: I'm curious; care to post that link to your tool?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Wow, haven't thought about this in years.  I put it up on Sourceforge almost 6 years ago: https://sourceforge.net/projects/mstestreportgen/

Answer (score 6):

Have all test classes inherit from a base test class that does the measurement.

In the general case you need to pipe the output message to something more useful (like a logger).

```
[TestClass]
public abstract class TestClassBase2
{
    protected TestContext testContextInstance;

    public TestContext TestContext
    {
        get { return testContextInstance; }
        set { testContextInstance = value; }
    }

    protected System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch _stopWatch;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void TestInitializeBase()
    {
        _stopWatch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
    }


    [TestCleanup]
    public void TestCleanupBase()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Done - Total Test time: {0} ms - {1}",
                                            _stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds, TestContext.TestName);
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class TempTests : TestClassBase2
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TempTest()
    {
        // outputs: 
        // Done - Total Test time: 3 ms - TempTest
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could always run the unit tests more times and then divide the total time by the times you ran them. This would essentially be an average though, so if you are looking for low or high spots then this is not the best thing to do.

Comment: the tests would have to be run multiple times during one test run - I can't see a way of doing this without adding a loop in every test method, which isn't ideal. Is there a way to add a test to a test run more than once?